# Why a structure sheaf is a vector bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Q. Why a structure sheaf is a vector bundle?

For example, in the following youtube, in 4:27, Takuro Mochizuki uses a strucure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ as an example of vector bundle; $E=\mathcal{O}_X$.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuTIgdH7n1k

Comment: It “is” (= corresponds to) the trivial vector bundle of rank 1. In general we think of locally free $O_X$-modules of finite rank as vector bundles.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682328/equivalence-of-categories-of-vector-bundles-and-locally-free-sheaves) [has](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597356/vector-bundle-associated-to-a-locally-free-sheaf) [been](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2725664/vector-bundle-locally-free-sheaf) covered extensively here before.